# Is it possible to create a Gbit network with cross-cable?

Tags: cable

If I want to connect two NIC, then I ""must"" use cross-cabling. But: Can I create a Gbit network with a cross-cable?

p.s.: The question is for cross-cable!!

Comment: What is "cross-cable?" (since your comments on Mark's answer imply that you think it's not the same as a crossover cable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are connecting two GbE NICs, you do **not** need a crossover cable. GbE NICs [auto-detect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX#Auto-MDIX) what's on the other end and transmit accordingly.

That said, the answer to your question is "yes". You can have a point to point network that's 1Gb with a crossover cable as long as that cable meets all of the other requirements.

Comment: I updated the Qeustion!!

Comment: @LanceBaynes I think that you should read my answer and the links that I provided.

Comment: You mean that crossover cable is not needed in 2011? Thats okay. But I asked about cross-cabling. [fixme]

Comment: @LanceBaynes What does 2011 have to do with anything? Mark stated If you have two GibE NICs it will transfer at 1GB with standard cat6 or crossover cat6. Is cross-cabling not the same thing as crossover?

Comment: cross-cabling = crossover

Comment: @LanceBaynes Then I've already answered your question thoroughly.